# How to understand ... in java method para list

Tags: java

How to understand this piece of code in java:

```
public static class header

{
    public class2 fields[];

    public header(class2... template)
    {
        // some initialization
    }
 }
```

How to understand ... in the para list?

Does means that we should input class2[] when we invoke this method?

Thanks for your insight.

Comment: http://www.deitel.com/articles/java_tutorials/20060106/VariableLengthArgumentLists.html

Answer (score 5):

The three dots `...` mean that the constructor can be called with a variable number of arguments. See: [Varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

Inside the constructor, `template` will look like an array (its type will be `class2[]`).